# Filtering MySQL results using polymorphism

Tags: php, mysql, sql, polymorphism

**I have method setup in my 'reporting' class that fetch results based on date input, for example:**

```
public function total_things_to_date() {

    return mysqli_num_rows($this -> db -> blank_query(" SELECT `thing_id`
                                                        FROM `things`
                                                        WHERE `client_id` = '{$_SESSION['client_id']}'
                                                        AND `thatid` IN (" . $this -> db -> prepareInClause($this -> that_id_array) . ")"));

}
```

I am looking for ideas on how I could go about adding a filter to this query without having to rewrite the method... for instance if I was going to filter by `department_id` and I HAD to rewrite the method I could append an `AND` clause:

```
public function total_things_to_date() {

    return mysqli_num_rows($this -> db -> blank_query(" SELECT `thing_id`
                                                        FROM `things`
                                                        WHERE `client_id` = '{$_SESSION['client_id']}'
                                                        AND `thatid` IN (" . $this -> db -> prepareInClause($this -> that_id_array) . ")
                                                        AND `deptid` = '$deptid'"));

}
```

**Alternatively, I could parse arguments to the method to filter the results:**

```
public function total_things_to_date($where = NULL, $selector = NULL) {

    if($where != NULL && $selector != NULL) {

        return mysqli_num_rows($this -> db -> blank_query(" SELECT `thing_id`
                                                            FROM `things`
                                                            WHERE `client_id` = '{$_SESSION['client_id']}'
                                                            AND `thatid` IN (" . $this -> db -> prepareInClause($this -> that_id_array) . ")
                                                            AND `deptid` = '$deptid'"));

    } else {

        //some array checks etc.

        $filterString = "";
        for($i=0;$i<count($where); $i++) {
            $filterString .= "AND `$where[$i]` = '$selector[$i]'";
        }

        return mysqli_num_rows($this -> db -> blank_query(" SELECT `thing_id`
                                                            FROM `things`
                                                            WHERE `client_id` = '{$_SESSION['client_id']}'
                                                            AND `thatid` IN (" . $this -> db -> prepareInClause($this -> that_id_array) . ")
                                                            $filterString"));

    }

}
```

This would work fine but is there a less ugly way / is there a preferred method for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your data as an array of strings:

```
$conditions = array("`dept_id`=1","`some_id`=2");

public function total_things_to_date( $conditions ) 
{
    $query = "SELECT `thing_id`
             FROM `things`
             WHERE `client_id` = '{$_SESSION['client_id']}'
             AND `thatid` IN (" . $this -> db -> prepareInClause($this -> that_id_array) . ")";
    $query .= implode( "AND", $conditions );
    return mysqli_num_rows($this -> db -> blank_query( $query );
}
```

Same thing but a little cleaner.